# How to get Google User Information from Token

Tags: api, xamarin.forms, google-oauth

I have an app that uses Google Authentication to sign in. After getting the user id token, I need to get this information from the user's profile:

Email
FullName
Profile Picture.

I've seen an example using this endpoint:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=ID

But this endpoint is not worked for me.

How can I get these profile information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this URL : https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=access_token.

This URL will return following Information

```
public class GoogleAuthClass
{
        public string email { get; set; }
        public bool email_verified { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string picture { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Plugin.GoogleClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.GoogleClient) nuget and follow [this](https://www.xamboy.com/2019/11/19/social-media-authentication-google-login-in-xamarin-forms/) Tutorial.

You will be able to access all the properties from the Google API and manage them as you require.

NOTE: This tutorial uses Firebase Auth.

More information can be seen at:
https://www.xamboy.com/2019/11/19/social-media-authentication-google-login-in-xamarin-forms/